# java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer one more time

Tags: java, android

I will take two numbers from user, but this number from `EditText` must be converted to `int`. I think it should be working, but I still have problem with compilation code in Android Studio.

**CatLog** show error in line with:

```
int wiek = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString());
```

Below is my full Android code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int Wynik; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        int Tmax, RT;
        EditText wiekEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inWiek);
        EditText tspoczEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inTspocz);
        int wiek = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString());
        int tspocz = Integer.parseInt(tspoczEditText.getText().toString());

        Tmax = 220 - wiek;
        RT = Tmax - tspocz;
        Wynik = 70*RT/100 + tspocz;

        final EditText tempWiekEdit = wiekEditText;
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);   //Do TabHost'a z layoutu

        tabHost.setup();                         

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Calc");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Calc);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Calc");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hints");                    
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Hints);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Hints");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        final Button Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);      
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"blablabla"+ "Wynik",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        wiekEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {      

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                Btn.setEnabled(!(tempWiekEdit.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `wiekEditText.getText().toString().trim()`

Comment: how sure are you that `wiekEditText` has inputted numbers in it?

Comment: please check if(wiekEditText.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){int wiek = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString());}

Comment: +SparkOn with .trim() is this same error
+Rod_Algonquin This app don't run so nobody have chance to put something different than numbers ;)

Comment: may be the input number conatains whitespace try printing the number and check it

Comment: try `Integer.valueOf` in place of `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking the layout XML, and by reading the problem description that you want to take 2 numbers from user, I can only assume that **those 2 `EditText`s are empty** when the activity is started.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    EditText wiekEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inWiek);
    EditText tspoczEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inTspocz);

    // edit text are still empty...
    int wiek = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString()); // error occurs!
    int tspocz = Integer.parseInt(tspoczEditText.getText().toString());

    ...

}
```

You probably want to parse the number **after user interaction**, perhaps by putting the code to `OnClickListener`, or `TextWatcher`

This example is using `OnClickListener`. The calculation will be done after user clicks the button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // add 'final'
    final EditText wiekEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inWiek);
    final EditText tspoczEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inTspocz);

    // remove offending code

    final EditText tempWiekEdit = wiekEditText;
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    ...

    final Button Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);      
    Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // move the parsing code here
            int Tmax, RT;
            int wiek = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString());
            int tspocz = Integer.parseInt(tspoczEditText.getText().toString());

            Tmax = 220 - wiek;
            RT = Tmax - tspocz;
            Wynik = 70*RT/100 + tspocz;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"blablabla"+ Wynik,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    ...

}
```

-or-

to prevent the error, **put default number** for the first time by adding `android:text="0"` on the layout XML.

```
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/inTspocz"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:hint="Your resting heart rate (Hint)" 
    android:text="0" />
```

Comment: In XML it is like that
 <EditText
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/inTspocz"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:hint="Your resting heart rate   (Hint)" />

Comment: So I must change android:hint="something" for android:text="something"?

Comment: You can put both, `hint` for input hint (if the `EditText` is empty), and `text` for default text.

Comment: Ok, When I put android:text="0" on the layout XML. It's working fine
But with android:text="some text" on the layout XML. I have error during compilation

Comment: If you put something other than number for `text`, the app will throw `NumberFormatException` since it tries to parse text, not a number. Refer to the updated answer for the example.

Comment: Ok, but what can I do if I want run this app without errors and also have "hint" text in my input box.
When I put android:text"0" then it's work but I lost hint text from inputbox, just 0 replaced this text.

Comment: Yes, but how I tell, then "0" is on input_box not text from Android:hint
http://s28.postimg.org/7djprxsdp/App.jpg

Comment: Just remove the `android:text="0"`... and you won't get the text from `hint` if you use `getText()`.

Comment: If I remove android:text="0" than I will have this same what before 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Comment: I haven't seen your modification on top window.
Now it is working perfect.
Thank you for your time, now I need to study these changes in my former code :)

Answer (score 1):

`NuberFormatException` can be thrown when you try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an int, a float, or any other Java numeric type. Add the following statement check what is the output.

```
System.out.println(wiekEditText.getText().toString());
```

This might be help to identify what your string returns. There is no mistake in your `wiekEditText.getText().toString()`.

Comment: I have this code in Android Studio and this error happen during compilation, not during perform some data in to input box.

Comment: that means `System.out.println(wiekEditText.getText().toString());` returns the intended output?? Give your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Your input may contains white spaces in leading or trailing or both. You can try with

```
int wiek = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Why [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)?

Eg:

```
   try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(" 12 ");
        System.out.println(num);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(" 12 ".trim());
        System.out.println(num);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
    }
```

Out put:

```
   Error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 12 "
   12
```

In this case if

```
   `wiekEditText.getText().toString()`
```

is `null`

You should use validation like

```
     int num = Integer.parseInt(wiekEditText.getText().toString()!=null
                                 ?wiekEditText.getText().toString().trim():"0");
```

Comment: @Quzziy what contains your input? is it `null`?

Comment: Yes I think it is null, when I put android:text="0" on the layout XML.
Like Andrew T. told me. Then I dont have error in compilation. But then I have '0' in my inputbox not my text from "hint"

Comment: @Quzziy you can't convert `null` to `int`. you should use validation. check my updated answer.

Comment: I was change my code for yours, but I it's this same problem during compilation, On this moment only android:text="0" on the layout XML helps, but then I lost my text from android:hint

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the number you are trying to parse is not bigger than 2,147,483,647 or -2,147,483,647 which is the integer max value.
So, in this case you may need to use

```
long varName = Long.parseLong(yourStringVar);
```