# Is it possible to use [TextWatcher for button disable control] for two EditText?

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code below, to make my button disabled until first input box received some numbers.
Problem is when I press the button before second input recieve numbers, then app is crashing.

First input var is `firstEdittext` and second is `secondEditText`

```
firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Btn.setEnabled(!(firstEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to use this TextWatcher for both?
Or I need to use another method for make my button disable

Comment: pl share your stack trace

Comment: Background issue: he's using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25478968/2821954) for the button's click listener. I believe, in this case, the error is caused by trying to parse second (empty) text.

Comment: I get crash if I have empty second or both text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by trying to parse empty text from `secondEditText`. In this case, you need to set the `TextWatcher` to both `EditText`s.

You can do it by defining a named `TextWatcher` in the class, then set both `EditText`s to use this. You also need to fix the checking condition for enabling the button.

Inside `onCreate()`:

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Btn.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(firstEditText.getText()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(secondEditText.getText()));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(tw);
secondEditText.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: Then where can I define (tw)?

Comment: You can define it in your class as a class variable (before `onCreate()`), or you can define it inside `onCreate()`, just before `firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(tw);`

Comment: Idk, I define it like a TextWatcher tw; before onCreate()
and it's not working, I must useing wrong define

Comment: TextWatcher tw =  (TextWatcher) findViewById(R.id.tw)
But still dont have an idea how connect tw to good object